# 大きなファイルの半角カタカナを全角カタカナに変換したい

Tags: テキストファイル, 日本語

大きなXMLファイルがあり、半角カタカナを全角カタカナに変換しないと使えない事があります。

約一万行あるのでテキストエディタは使えません。オンライン変換も難しいです。

私はMac OS Xを使っています。プログラムで変換する場合、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

Comment: `Perl`を使って変換する。

Comment: `perl`って良いけど、どうするか？

Comment: XMLで使えないというのは、おそらくエンコードがUNICODEでないのだろうから、まず該当ファイルのエンコードを調べてエンコードを変更するようなプログラムの中で`tr`を使うなど(変換できないコードは報告？)する。 「使えない」場合の最小限の例（小さなXMLの具体的例、使えないの例（状況・事由））を提示すると回答も付くかも知れません。

Comment: エンコード問題じゃなくて、半角問題だ。濁点や半濁点は文字であるから`tr`は使えない。`ｶ`を`カ`に変換しても、`ｶﾞ`なら濁点が残る。

Comment: 濁点・半濁点がtr変換できないというのが問題なら該当するパターンは知れているので`s///`で変換できると思う。

Comment: 半角・全角変換については、`Unicode`モジュール（[Unicodeの使用例](http://www003.upp.so-net.ne.jp/NAMBOKU/perl/perl0364.html)）, `Encode`モジュール（[Encodeの使用例](http://www003.upp.so-net.ne.jp/NAMBOKU/perl/perl0362.html)）などを使うといいかも。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

brew等で [nkf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nkf) コマンドをインストールしてはいかがでしょう。

デフォルト（もしくは `-X` オプション）で半角カナが全角カナに変換されます。

> By default, X0201 kana is converted into X0208 kana. For X0201 kana, SO/SI , SSO and ESC- (-I methods are supported. For automatic code detection, nkf assumes no X0201 kana in Shift_JIS. To accept X0201 in Shift_JIS, use -X, -x or -S.
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/1/nkf

※[JIS X0201](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201) におけるカタカナがいわゆる半角カタカナと言われるもののようです。

```
$ cat in.txt
☀abcdあいうアイウｱｲｳ☂

$ nkf --utf8 in.txt
☀abcdあいうアイウアイウ☂
```